# VirtualBox Ubuntu "Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization" -> "Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 11"

Tags: 18.04, gnome, virtualbox, gnome-shell, virtualization

I have created a VirtualBox VM on my Windows 10 with Ubuntu 18.04

```
  Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
  Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-42-generic
  Architecture: x86-64
```

I wanted to share this VM with others for a Meetup. I tried a simple Copy & Paste and an OCI export. The vm is starting but lots of apps will crash the UI. This leads to a logout.

The moment I start any application the screen-size changes several times. The menu disappears and the user will be logged out.

How can I fix this either before exporting or after exporting but than with minimal effort. It would be good if the user must not be removed/re-added.

Before moving this vm to any other pc it works like a charm.

**syslog**

```
Aug 21 15:09:51 ubuntu-VirtualBox dbus-daemon[4088]: [session uid=1000 pid=4088] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.portal.Documents' unit='xdg-document-portal.service' requested by ':1.74' (uid=1000 pid=4838 comm="/snap/bin/chromium " label="unconfined")
Aug 21 15:09:51 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[4058]: Starting flatpak document portal service...
Aug 21 15:09:51 ubuntu-VirtualBox dbus-daemon[4088]: [session uid=1000 pid=4088] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.portal.Documents'
Aug 21 15:09:51 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[4058]: Started flatpak document portal service.
Aug 21 15:09:52 ubuntu-VirtualBox chrome[4838]: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Aug 21 15:09:52 ubuntu-VirtualBox kernel: [ 1851.212234] audit: type=1107 audit(1598015392.176:56): pid=534 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=4838 label="snap.chromium.chromium"
Aug 21 15:09:52 ubuntu-VirtualBox kernel: [ 1851.212234]  exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'
Aug 21 15:09:52 ubuntu-VirtualBox chrome[4838]: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Aug 21 15:09:52 ubuntu-VirtualBox chromium_chromium.desktop[4838]: [4989:4989:0821/150952.397684:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(150)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
Aug 21 15:09:53 ubuntu-VirtualBox dbus-daemon[4088]: [session uid=1000 pid=4088] Activating service name='io.snapcraft.Settings' requested by ':1.79' (uid=1000 pid=5066 comm="dbus-send --print-reply=literal --session --dest=i" label="snap.chromium.chromium (enforce)")
Aug 21 15:09:53 ubuntu-VirtualBox dbus-daemon[4088]: [session uid=1000 pid=4088] Successfully activated service 'io.snapcraft.Settings'
Aug 21 15:09:53 ubuntu-VirtualBox io.snapcraft.Settings[4088]: userd.go:98: Starting snap userd
Aug 21 15:09:53 ubuntu-VirtualBox gnome-session[4091]: gnome-session-binary[4091]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 11
Aug 21 15:09:53 ubuntu-VirtualBox gnome-session-binary[4091]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 11
Aug 21 15:09:53 ubuntu-VirtualBox gsd-media-keys[4437]: g_variant_get_va: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
Aug 21 15:09:53 ubuntu-VirtualBox gsd-media-keys[4437]: g_variant_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
Aug 21 15:09:54 ubuntu-VirtualBox org.gnome.Shell.desktop[5188]: current session already has an ibus-daemon.
Aug 21 15:09:54 ubuntu-VirtualBox dbus-daemon[534]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.GeoClue2' unit='geoclue.service' requested by ':1.174' (uid=1000 pid=5188 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Aug 21 15:09:54 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Starting Location Lookup Service...
Aug 21 15:09:54 ubuntu-VirtualBox gnome-shell[5188]: Telepathy is not available, chat integration will be disabled.
Aug 21 15:09:54 ubuntu-VirtualBox dbus-daemon[534]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.GeoClue2'
Aug 21 15:09:54 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Started Location Lookup Service.
Aug 21 15:09:54 ubuntu-VirtualBox gnome-shell[5188]: JS WARNING: [/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/appIcons.js 1028]: unreachable code after return statement
Aug 21 15:09:54 ubuntu-VirtualBox gnome-shell[5188]: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspaceThumbnail.js 891]: reference to undefined property "_switchWorkspaceNotifyId"
Aug 21 15:09:55 ubuntu-VirtualBox gnome-shell[5188]: [AppIndicatorSupport-DEBUG] Registering StatusNotifierItem :1.71/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/software_update_available
Aug 21 15:09:55 ubuntu-VirtualBox gnome-shell[5188]: [AppIndicatorSupport-DEBUG] Registering StatusNotifierItem :1.71/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/livepatch
Aug 21 15:09:55 ubuntu-VirtualBox gnome-shell[5188]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
Aug 21 15:09:55 ubuntu-VirtualBox gsd-color[4431]: unable to get EDID for xrandr-Virtual1: unable to get EDID for output
Aug 21 15:09:55 ubuntu-VirtualBox gsd-color[4431]: message repeated 3 times: [ unable to get EDID for xrandr-Virtual1: unable to get EDID for output]
Aug 21 15:09:55 ubuntu-VirtualBox gnome-shell[5188]: JS ERROR: Exception in callback for signal: position-changed: TypeError: this._rect is null#012getCurrentRect@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/keyboard.js:561:22#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012_onFocusPositionChanged@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/keyboard.js:643:20#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012_emit@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128:27#012_setCurrentWindow/this._currentWindowPositionId<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/keyboard.js:535:21
Aug 21 15:09:56 ubuntu-VirtualBox gnome-shell[5188]: GNOME Shell started at Fri Aug 21 2020 15:09:54 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Aug 21 15:09:56 ubuntu-VirtualBox gnome-shell[5188]: JS ERROR: Exception in callback for signal: position-changed: TypeError: this._rect is null#012getCurrentRect@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/keyboard.js:561:22#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012_onFocusPositionChanged@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/keyboard.js:643:20#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012_emit@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128:27#012_setCurrentWindow/this._currentWindowPositionId<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/keyboard.js:535:21
Aug 21 15:11:08 ubuntu-VirtualBox gnome-session[4091]: gnome-session-binary[4091]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 11
Aug 21 15:11:08 ubuntu-VirtualBox gnome-session-binary[4091]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 11
Aug 21 15:11:08 ubuntu-VirtualBox gsd-media-keys[4437]: g_variant_get_va: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
Aug 21 15:11:08 ubuntu-VirtualBox gsd-media-keys[4437]: g_variant_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
Aug 21 15:11:09 ubuntu-VirtualBox org.gnome.Shell.desktop[5293]: current session already has an ibus-daemon.
Aug 21 15:11:09 ubuntu-VirtualBox dbus-daemon[534]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.GeoClue2' unit='geoclue.service' requested by ':1.177' (uid=1000 pid=5293 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Aug 21 15:11:09 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Starting Location Lookup Service...
Aug 21 15:11:09 ubuntu-VirtualBox gnome-shell[5293]: Telepathy is not available, chat integration will be disabled.
Aug 21 15:11:09 ubuntu-VirtualBox dbus-daemon[534]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.GeoClue2'
Aug 21 15:11:09 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Started Location Lookup Service.
Aug 21 15:11:09 ubuntu-VirtualBox gnome-shell[5293]: JS WARNING: [/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/appIcons.js 1028]: unreachable code after return statement
Aug 21 15:11:09 ubuntu-VirtualBox gnome-shell[5293]: [AppIndicatorSupport-DEBUG] Registering StatusNotifierItem :1.71/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/software_update_available
Aug 21 15:11:09 ubuntu-VirtualBox gnome-shell[5293]: [AppIndicatorSupport-DEBUG] Registering StatusNotifierItem :1.71/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/livepatch
Aug 21 15:11:09 ubuntu-VirtualBox gsd-color[4431]: unable to get EDID for xrandr-Virtual1: unable to get EDID for output
Aug 21 15:11:10 ubuntu-VirtualBox gnome-shell[5293]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.portal.Error.NotFound: No entry for geolocation
Aug 21 15:11:10 ubuntu-VirtualBox gnome-shell[5293]: JS ERROR: Exception in callback for signal: position-changed: TypeError: this._rect is null#012getCurrentRect@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/keyboard.js:561:22#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012_onFocusPositionChanged@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/keyboard.js:643:20#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012_emit@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128:27#012_setCurrentWindow/this._currentWindowPositionId<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/keyboard.js:535:21
Aug 21 15:11:10 ubuntu-VirtualBox gnome-shell[5293]: GNOME Shell started at Fri Aug 21 2020 15:11:09 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Aug 21 15:11:11 ubuntu-VirtualBox gnome-shell[5293]: JS ERROR: Exception in callback for signal: position-changed: TypeError: this._rect is null#012getCurrentRect@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/keyboard.js:561:22#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012_onFocusPositionChanged@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/keyboard.js:643:20#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012_emit@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128:27#012_setCurrentWindow/this._currentWindowPositionId<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/keyboard.js:535:21
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox gnome-session[4091]: gnome-session-binary[4091]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 11
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox gnome-session-binary[4091]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 11
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox gnome-session[4091]: gnome-session-binary[4091]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' respawning too quickly
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox gnome-session[4091]: gnome-session-binary[4091]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox gnome-session-binary[4091]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox gnome-session-binary[4091]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' respawning too quickly
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox gnome-session-binary[4091]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox kernel: [ 1931.348657] rfkill: input handler enabled
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox at-spi-bus-launcher[4231]: XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox at-spi-bus-launcher[4231]:       after 2573 requests (2573 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox gsd-power[4390]: gsd-power: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox gsd-xsettings[4410]: gsd-xsettings: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox gsd-media-keys[4437]: gsd-media-keys: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox gsd-keyboard[4435]: gsd-keyboard: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox update-notifier[4694]: update-notifier: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox gnome-terminal-[4623]: gnome-terminal-server: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4076]: (**) Option "fd" "20"
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4076]: (II) event0  - Power Button: device removed
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4076]: (**) Option "fd" "23"
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4076]: (II) event1  - Sleep Button: device removed
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4076]: (**) Option "fd" "24"
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4076]: (II) event3  - Video Bus: device removed
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4076]: (**) Option "fd" "25"
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4076]: (II) event6  - VirtualBox mouse integration: device removed
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4076]: (**) Option "fd" "26"
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4076]: (II) event5  - VirtualBox USB Tablet: device removed
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4076]: (**) Option "fd" "27"
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4076]: (II) event2  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4076]: (**) Option "fd" "28"
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4076]: (II) event4  - ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: device removed
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4076]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4076]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:68
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox chromium_chromium.desktop[4838]: [5012:5012:0821/151112.368178:ERROR:x11_util.cc(112)] X IO error received (X server probably went away)
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox gsd-color[4431]: gsd-color: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox gsd-wacom[4421]: gsd-wacom: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox gsd-clipboard[4428]: gsd-clipboard: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox nautilus-deskto[4503]: nautilus-desktop: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox chromium_chromium.desktop[4838]: [4838:4838:0821/151112.392911:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_x11.cc(63)] X IO error received (X server probably went away)
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[4058]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[4058]: gnome-terminal-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4076]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4076]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:66
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4076]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4076]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:69
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4076]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4076]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:70
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4076]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4076]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:67
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4076]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4076]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:65
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4076]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4076]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:64
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[4076]: (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox gsd-color[3935]: unable to get EDID for xrandr-Virtual-1: unable to get EDID for output
Aug 21 15:11:12 ubuntu-VirtualBox gsd-color[3935]: message repeated 2 times: [ unable to get EDID for xrandr-Virtual-1: unable to get EDID for output]
Aug 21 15:11:17 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
Aug 21 15:11:17 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[4058]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service - Apple File Conduit monitor...
Aug 21 15:11:17 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[4058]: Stopped target Default.
Aug 21 15:11:17 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[4058]: Stopping D-Bus User Message Bus...
Aug 21 15:11:17 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[4058]: Stopping flatpak document portal service...
Aug 21 15:11:17 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[4058]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service - Media Transfer Protocol monitor...
Aug 21 15:11:17 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[4058]: Stopping Accessibility services bus...
Aug 21 15:11:17 ubuntu-VirtualBox io.snapcraft.Settings[4088]: Exiting on terminated.
Aug 21 15:11:17 ubuntu-VirtualBox gvfsd[4276]: A connection to the bus can't be made
Aug 21 15:11:17 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[4058]: Stopping Evolution address book service...
Aug 21 15:11:17 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[4058]: Stopping sandboxed app permission store...
Aug 21 15:11:17 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[4058]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service - disk device monitor...
Aug 21 15:11:17 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[4058]: Stopping Evolution calendar service...
Aug 21 15:11:17 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[4058]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service - GNOME Online Accounts monitor...
Aug 21 15:11:17 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[4058]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service - digital camera monitor...
Aug 21 15:11:17 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[4058]: Stopping Virtual filesystem metadata service...
Aug 21 15:11:17 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[4058]: Stopping Evolution source registry...
Aug 21 15:11:17 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[4058]: Stopping Virtual filesystem service...
Aug 21 15:11:17 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[4058]: xdg-permission-store.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 21 15:11:17 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[4058]: xdg-permission-store.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 21 15:11:17 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[4058]: Stopped sandboxed app permission store.
Aug 21 15:11:17 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[4058]: Stopped Virtual filesystem service - disk device monitor.
Aug 21 15:11:17 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[4058]: Stopped Virtual filesystem service - Apple File Conduit monitor.
Aug 21 15:11:17 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[4058]: Stopped Virtual filesystem metadata service.
Aug 21 15:11:17 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[4058]: Stopped D-Bus User Message Bus.
Aug 21 15:11:17 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[4058]: Stopped Accessibility services bus.
Aug 21 15:11:17 ubuntu-VirtualBox systemd[4058]: Stopped Virtual filesystem service.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I "fixed" the problem. It was related to an activated **Hyper-V** feature. After turning this **off** it works. Theoretically VirtualBox shall support Hyper-V since version 6. But it looks like it was not working as expected.